# R data.table grouped operation returning wrong values if names are not in the same order by group?

Tags: r, data.table

I am computing an operation by group in `data.table` where the function returns a list of the same length for each group, and with the same names. However, it seems that if the names of the lists produced are not always in the same order by group, then the values can be incorrectly assigned in the final output.

Here is a contrived example that illustrates this behaviour:

```
f <- function(x, allcols){
  l <- floor(log2(length(x)))
  y <- c(1:l, l)
  names(y) <- paste0(c(rep("n",length(y)-1),"s"), y)
  y[setdiff(allcols, names(y))] <- 0
  return(as.list(y))
}


d <- data.table(x = rep(1,30), group = c(rep(1,14), rep(2,16)))
allcols <- c(paste0("n",1:4), paste0("s",3:4))

x1 <- d[group==1,x]
x2 <- d[group==2,x]
f(x1,allcols)
f(x2,allcols)
d[, f(x, allcols), by = group]
```

You can see that the output produced when run on groups individually is different than the output obtained when done as a grouped operation using `data.table`. This may be a highly specific usage case but it seems like this could produce incorrect output in some instances. Is this intentional? And what is the best way to avoid this behaviour in this case?

Answer (score 0):

I added one line to your function, `y <- y[allcols]`. This sort the output in `y` based on the content in `allcols`.

```
library(data.table)

f <- function(x, allcols){
  l <- floor(log2(length(x)))
  y <- c(1:l, l)
  names(y) <- paste0(c(rep("n",length(y)-1),"s"), y)
  y[setdiff(allcols, names(y))] <- 0
  y <- y[allcols]
  return(as.list(y))
}
```

Now the outputs are the same when you applied the function to a vector and to a `data.table` by group.

```
f(x1, allcols = allcols)
# $n1
# [1] 1
# 
# $n2
# [1] 2
# 
# $n3
# [1] 3
# 
# $n4
# [1] 0
# 
# $s3
# [1] 3
# 
# $s4
# [1] 0

f(x2, allcols = allcols)
# $n1
# [1] 1
# 
# $n2
# [1] 2
# 
# $n3
# [1] 3
# 
# $n4
# [1] 4
# 
# $s3
# [1] 0
# 
# $s4
# [1] 4

d[, f(x = x, allcols), by = group]
#    group n1 n2 n3 n4 s3 s4
# 1:     1  1  2  3  0  3  0
# 2:     2  1  2  3  4  0  4
```

I don't know why your original code does not work. But my guess is this has something to do with `rbindlist`, which combines a list of data frame. I thought it should combine rows based on the same column names, like what `bind_rows` from `dplyr` does. But it seems like the default behavior is combine rows by position. Therefore, it becomes important that your function returns the results with the same order for each group. check `?rbindlist` and the explanation for `use.names` for more details. Assuming that when applying the function by `group` is calling `rbindlist` in the background, I think it should return a warning if the column orders are not the same. But it does not.